# Load external JavaScript file with document.write into AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, document.write

I got this external JavaScript file(Ad file), which has a document.write() in it. I have tried loading it with $http, and then injecting it into a document.createElement, but the Ad server doesn't support this method; $http.get.

I have tried ng-include in a script, but no work.

I need to load the script in the file, and the run the script. How do I do it?

`<script ng-src=""></script>` doesn't work either. It does not run the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to inject script on runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this directive - helped made by my friend Dennis - that works in my situation. Hope it can help someone.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('emediateScript', emediateScript);

    /* @ngInject */
    function emediateScript(Ad, $http) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ad: '=ad',
            }
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs){

            var _el = angular.element(element);

            var url = 'http://www.http.com';

            var request = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'X-Authentication': undefined
                }
            };

            if (url) {
                $http(request).then(function(response) {
                    var html = response.data.substr(16);
                    html = html.substring(0, html.length - 4);
                    _el.html(html);
                });
            }

        };
    };
})();
```

And HTML was;

```
<emediate-script></emediate-script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery (which it sounds like you are), there is a [method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for this:

```
$.getScript("http://my/script/url.js");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I got this now;

Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Which makes me think I'm a step closer! Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create a `<script>` tag with jqLite?

```
$('body').append('<script type="application/javascript" src="http://localhost/test.js"></script>');
```

It seems to work perfectly with my test file.

Comment: It creates the <script> element, but does not load the script. Thanks anyway, it was a good simpel solution.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the script itself? Does it work for you if you add it to the html statically via script tag? Also, are there any errors in console? If you could show us the code, it would be great.

Comment: @TommyJepsen It should be `text/javascript`

Comment: Well, when I programmatically put it in a <script type="text/javascript">, it works, but crashes my whole application. @user860478

Comment: Thanks @RahilWazir but still no success. It doesn't visualize anything.